# How to mark a task to not execute in a Flow?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I have a flow in SAS Enterprise Guide but for debug reasons I want some tasks to run and others don't.
Is there a way to tell the flow to not execute some tasks? F.E. an export task.

Answer (score 1):

http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/guide/sasegforprogrammersGoodies.htm

Most of the way down, under `How do you make sure a task (or program) has completed successfully before performing the next one?`:

> In SAS Enterprise Guide 4.2 and later, you can add one or more
>   conditions to a task that control whether the task (and any items that
>   follow it) will run.  A condition can be based upon a prompt value,
>   date/time conditions, a value in SAS data set, or macro variable. 
>   It's these last two type that can be very powerful, since you can add
>   almost any value that you want to a SAS data set or macro variable and
>   check for it within a condition.
>       To ensure that a particular task has what it needs before continuing, use a Query Builder or SAS program step in the project to
>   populate a value into a SAS data set. Then create a condition
>   (right-click on the task and select Condition->Add), and create a
>   condition based upon the expected value within the data set you
>   created.

In your case, you should have a macro variable or a value in a sas dataset defined for debug, like %let debug=0; or %let debug=1; and then use that value for your condition.

Answer (score 0):

If this is not something you plan to repeat frequently, a quick solution would be to select the processes you'd like to execute (Ctrl+click) and  choose "Run Selected" as your run option.